# How to use mongodb query operation on a very large database (have 3 shards of around 260-300 million in each)

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, mongodb-query, sharding

I have to find data in between different date ranges column in a sharded database having total of around 800 million documents. I am using this query:

```
cursordata=event.aggregate([{"$match":{}},{"$unwind":},{"$project":{}}])
```

However, when I change it to a pandas dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(cursordata)
```

It is taking for ever and not working at all, it just got stuck.

I have 2 choices:

1. Either keep doing query for different conditions directly from mongodb or
2. After changing to data to dataframe, perform operation for different conditions

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: do you have an index that the match stage can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we have a sample of documents?
I think you should look for an index matching the fields you're querying.

As a reminder, try to keep in mind the [Equality, Sort, Range](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) rule in MongoDB indexing.
Besides, since you're in a sharded cluster you might want to have your sharding key in you query, otherwise the mongos will query all the shards (more info [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/distributed-queries/#read-operations-to-sharded-clusters))